# Updating For Each loop variable

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, for-loop

[image]

The aim is to find the circularity between value in column c and all values obtained from updated "firstvalue" variable which are comma separated and stored in column "M".

```
Sub circular()
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, firstvalue As String, secondvalue As String
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lr = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each rng In sh.Range("C5:C" & lr) 'iterating over each cell in column "c" from C5 till lastrow "lr". 
        firstvalue = rng.Offset(0, 10).value 'Corresponding cell value which is comma separated in column 
                                              "M" i:e after 10 columns from "C".    
        Dim n As Variant
        For Each n In Split(firstvalue, ",")   'Looping through each value obtained from split function.
        Set rng2 = sh.Range("C5:C" & lr).Find(Trim(n), LookIn:=xlValues)  'Finding that split value again 
                                                                          in column "C".
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then                                      'if exists in column c then get. 
        secondvalue = rng2.Offset(0, 10).value                           'corresponding cell values.    
        firstvalue = firstvalue & "," & secondvalue                      'now first value is concatenated 
                                                                          with initial firstvalue
        End If
        Next n                        
        MsgBox firstvalue
        'Now I want to iterate over updated "firstvalue" in split function and this goes on in circular 
         fashion until rng value exists in firstvalue. 
Next rng            'then change next rng and continue the above whole process for this value and so on.
End Sub
```

This code is working for initial firstvalue, can any one suggest any method to iterate over updated first value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please supplement your question with sample data from Column C and Column M to help us understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JohnSUN Thanks for the response, I have attached image now, kindly check. Thanks.

Comment: Thx! So, with this data you will get: for C5 - still nothing, for C6 (2) - only 1, for C7 (4/6,7) - result will be 6,7,2,1,4,6,7,2,1... and more, and more, and more again - an endless loop that ends with the free memory of your computer?

Comment: @JohnSUN yes you are righ but for C7 the predecessors list contains 4 which is also in task column. so the loop should stops here. Similar process for all C value. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your goal exactly, but this code should find all predecessors for each task:

```
Sub circular()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rTask As Range
Dim oCell As Range
Dim oFound As Range
Dim lr As Long, j As Long
Dim aPredecessors As Variant
Dim sCurTask As String
Dim secondValue As String
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lr = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rTask = sh.Range("C5:C" & lr)
    
    For Each oCell In rTask
        sCurTask = Trim(oCell.Text)
        aPredecessors = getPredecessors(Trim(oCell.Offset(0, 10).Text))
        j = LBound(aPredecessors)
        Do Until j > UBound(aPredecessors)
            secondValue = aPredecessors(j)
            If sCurTask = secondValue Then
                ReDim Preserve aPredecessors(j)
                Debug.Print "Task '" & sCurTask & "': Cyclic link '" & secondValue & "' for '" & Join(aPredecessors, ",") & "'!"
                aPredecessors(j) = aPredecessors(j) & " !!!"
            Else
                If secondValue <> vbNullString Then
                    Set oFound = rTask.Find(secondValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    If oFound Is Nothing Then
                        ReDim Preserve aPredecessors(j)
                        Debug.Print "Task '" & sCurTask & "': Task '" & secondValue & "' for '" & Join(aPredecessors, ",") & "' not found!"
                        aPredecessors(j) = aPredecessors(j) & " ???"
                    Else
                        Call addNewTasks(aPredecessors, Trim(oFound.Offset(0, 10).Text))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        oCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = Join(aPredecessors, ",")
    Next oCell
End Sub

Function getPredecessors(sPredecessors As String)
Dim i As Long
Dim aTemp As Variant, sRes As String
Dim sTest As String
    sRes = vbNullString
    aTemp = Split(sPredecessors, ",")
    For i = LBound(aTemp) To UBound(aTemp)
        sTest = Trim(aTemp(i))
        If InStr("," & sRes & ",", "," & sTest & ",") = 0 Then sRes = sRes & sTest & ","
    Next i
    If Len(sRes) > 1 Then sRes = Left(sRes, Len(sRes) - 1)
    getPredecessors = Split(sRes, ",")
End Function

Sub addNewTasks(aData As Variant, sPredecessors As String)
Dim i As Long, uB As Long
Dim aTemp As Variant
Dim sTest As String, sValid As String
    aTemp = Split(sPredecessors, ",")
    If UBound(aTemp) >= 0 Then ' Not empty
        sValid = "," & Join(aData, ",") & ","
        For i = LBound(aTemp) To UBound(aTemp)
            sTest = Trim(aTemp(i))
            If sTest <> vbNullString Then
                If InStr(sValid, "," & sTest & ",") = 0 Then
                    uB = UBound(aData) + 1
                    ReDim Preserve aData(uB)
                    aData(uB) = sTest
                    sValid = "," & Join(aData, ",") & ","
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Man! You are champ, but in the debug.print i want to find oFoundvalue, in other words in which oFound.offset(0,10).value, sCurTask Exists, so i will directly go to that value and change that value, do you think it is posible? And for large data set time complexity of this algorithm is very large, in other words it takes 5mins to read 1000rows of data, so any remedy for this issue ?

Comment: @Waqas Of course it posible: we can create a direct link to the error cell for quick navigation. For example, put the HYPERLINK() function in oCell.Offset (0, 12). I know this rough draft is far from ideal, I just wanted to make sure I read your code correctly and understood your purpose. This algorithm can and should be improved. Do you need a list of Predecessors in the order in which the corresponding tasks will be found? Or it can be in ascending order? Ordered structures can (usually) save a lot of time at the cost of slightly complicating of code.

Comment: Hello, yes you got my point exactly and your algorithm is working properly for my case. But the actual aim is to cerate a chain of predecessors for each task and check weather that chain contains that task or not, if found than debug.print "circular reference between task (for which we are making chain) and the task (that contains the task in it's m column). Printing those task to sheet is not necessary requirement just find the anomaly and pop ups by msgbox. Thanks.

Comment: I'll try to do it neatly. But it seems to me that MsgBox is not very well suited for a large set of 1000 rows. If only 5% of tasks are described incorrectly, then you will receive 50 pop-ups. I'll think about an alternative.

Comment: Yes that's right, i think alternate is we can use exit sub command after each pop up or create an array and then show it on msg box after the final check. Thanks.

Comment: @Waqas Thanks for waiting patiently. And many thanks for a very interesting problem! I had to try several different solution methods in order to increase the processing speed on the one hand, and on the other hand to achieve stable program behavior. Of course, Recursion turned out to be the fastest, but this method cannot process sets where a task is preceded by several dozen other tasks. Please see the [TasksInCycle.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ig3f3lkghzsyywg/TasksInCycle.xlsm?dl=0) file - I hope some of the suggested macros are helpful.

Comment: Hello Man! This is really awsome, but here is little bit confussion, what do you mean by error task column and what  it is the purpose of hyperlink ?

Comment: I was just trying to make it easier to find the source of the error - it is quite difficult to search for the desired task among thousands of data lines, and using a hyperlink, you can immediately jump to the task due to which the current task cannot be completed. For example, if on line 105 you see the message "Cycle: task 'Job 960' required the task 'Job 101'!", then you don't need to scroll down 855 rows, just click the hyperlink and make sure what is valid for 'Job 960' for some reason, 'Job 101' is indicated and fix it with the correct task name.

Comment: In order not to search for lines with errors throughout the sheet, they are additionally collected in the column "Error Task (s)" in a compact form and sorted in this order - missing tasks (for some reason, possibly due to a typo, they are not in column C ), circular references, and tasks that cannot be completed because they require some erroneous task to be completed first.

Comment: Ok John got it and definitely it is helpful, is it possible to just indicate the root cause which may casues multiple wrong tasks, so rather than scrolling by hyperlink just go to the root cause and fix so all other wrong will be automatically fix?

Comment: While you were writing this question, I was writing an answer to it - see the previous comment :-) Unfortunately, not every error has a source. For example, where do you go to find a missing task? In this case, the hyperlink links to the same row (I haven't come up with anything better)

Comment: Yes this is challange but sometimes single erroneous task causes multiple errors which are annoying and are only due to that one and not necessary to be fixed ? So any strategy to pick up that disturbing task and fix it ?

Comment: Yes indeed! The first hyperlinks in the Error Task (s) column are those "root" errors you are asking about. All the rest - with the text "Wrong task" - are already derived errors. It is enough to fix the "root" and derivatives will disappear by themselves.

Comment: Yes but i think they are order wise accroding to cell values in column c, so according to this changes position may change the root. Am i right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223479/discussion-between-johnsun-and-waqas).